# c# find characters in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have and Two dimensional array like this.

```
[A] [B] [C]
[D] [E] [F]
[G] [H] [I]
```

And I want a function that receive a string as parameter and return an array int[,] with a position of each Word of that string.

```
public int[,] GetPosition(string Word)
{
    int[,] coordenadas = new int[1, Word.Length];
    for (int value = 0; value < Word.Length; value++)
    {
        char letra = Word[value];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (array[i, j].Equals(letra.ToString()))
                {
                    coordenadas[0, j] = //??
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I call that function with a Word like `GetPosition("GEI")`

It has to return an array `{{3,1},{2,2},{3,3}}`

How can I build an `int[,]` with every position?

Comment: Does it have to be an int[,]? you could create a custom class with properties Row and Column of type int, then make a `List<T>` of type custom class and populate the properties of each object to correspond to the position in your letter array for the given word and `.Add` them to the `List<T>` which could be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I build an `int[,]` with every position?

You don't *want* an `int[,]`, you just want a vector (1-D array) where each *value* is set of two numbers. You could use a `Tuple<int, int>` or just a plain `int[]` or some other structure, depending on how you want to *use* the data..

So then to *set* the value in the array, you could do:

```
int[][] coordenadas= new int[][Word.Length];
...
    coordenadas[value] = new int[] {i, j};
```

Note that `coordenadas` does not seem to need to be a 2-D array.

Comment: Ya, I was gonna mention he could flatten it first, to try and simplify.